# How to create a node.js application for desktop, web and mobile with a single codebase?

Tags: node.js

Is there a way to compile a node.js application for multiple devices? I would like to use Electron for desktop (Chromium), NativeScript for mobile devices and also have a SPA for common browsers. There are many parts of this application that look alike - although those systems are not combatible between each others, there must be a way to share the key parts between each other.
Unfortunately there is not much information on the web about this issue, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've voted to close because the question is too broad, but here is some general information to help you develop more specific questions:

There are any number of ways to do what you're asking for. But generally you'll want an API capable of servicing all of your clients (the term API is being used very generally. It may not be a simple REST API you're looking for, depending on what you are trying to do). As for deploying your application to multiple platforms, you'll either need to find a library, framework, language, and/or emulator which supports UIs for all of your desired platforms, or create dedicated clients for each device, or a mix of the two. For simple HTML applications, React is one such front-end library/methodology/framework which can support multiple platforms through its various versions. You could use something such as Electron to pack up your application and make it look like a native app.